# Calling drawtobitmap() on transparent controls

Tags: c#, winforms, imaging

I have a transparent/opaque form that I was hoping to draw on to 'explain' what's going on in the program underneath said transparent form.

In order to evaluate what's going on, I need drawtobitmap to return what the control actually looks like on the screen with transparency but instead it simply captures a solid version of the form - essentially what it would look like if it didn't have an opacity value set.

Is there some OnPaint override trickery I can use to get around this or will I have to use graphics.copyfromscreen() with the relevant rectangle?

Comment: You might try sending the WM_PRINT message yourself (p/invoke `SendMessage()`), providing an `HDC` that references your own bitmap. Then you can initialize the bitmap as transparent (all pixels alpha of 0) instead of getting whatever `DrawToBitmap()` starts out with.

Comment: You are asking the window to draw itself so you just get what the window looks like, not what all the other windows that are visible underneath look like.  Sure, you need CopyFromScreen() to catch all of the pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `DrawToBitmap()` will only draw the window itself.
Transparency/opactiy cannot be seen in that context.

On the other side, `Graphics.CopyFromScreen()` will copy all pixels from the current graphics context, so this can make transparency/opactiy visible.